# Custom QRcodes with python qrcode module

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code

I'm trying to generate a customized qrcode, with a logo in the center, with the Python qrcode module.
Searching the web, many threads agree on using the PILImage module to compose the image with the 'composite' method and a function that returns a mask

```
def style_eyes(img):
   img_size = img.size[0]
   eye_size = 70 #default
   quiet_zone = 40 #default
   mask = Image.new('L', img.size, 0)
   draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
   draw.rectangle((40, 40, 110, 110), fill=255)
   draw.rectangle((img_size-110, 40, img_size-40, 110), fill=255)
   draw.rectangle((40, img_size-110, 110, img_size-40), fill=255)
   return mask
```

but apparently there is an error with the axes referring to the rectangle

`self.draw.draw_rectangle(xy, fill, 1) ValueError: x1 must be greater than or equal to x0`

Other topics take other approaches, but none of them worked.

From https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/ i got that

```
import qrcode
from qrcode.image.styledpil import StyledPilImage
from qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers.pil import RoundedModuleDrawer
from qrcode.image.styles.colormasks import RadialGradiantColorMask

qr = qrcode.QRCode(error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L)
qr.add_data('Some data')

img_1 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, module_drawer=RoundedModuleDrawer())
img_2 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, color_mask=RadialGradiantColorMask())
img_3 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, embeded_image_path="/path/to/image.png")
```

and I get two overlapping images.

In fact, the documentation available is very dry, without details on how to use the methods. I would like to know what the best approach would actually be and where to find out, if there is freely available, a complete documentation with all features, including methods and parameters.

I want a custom qrcode and I get syntax errors or two overlapping images.

Comment: Please include the full traceback message, so we can tell which of the three `.rectangle()` calls triggered the problem.  All of them look correct to me.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HP Core I5\Documents\py_lab\qrcode\maskqrcodetest.py", line 22, in <module>
    qr_eyes_img = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^